# Which pattern would you use to solve that kind of expression?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I have multiple states and multiple values, and well, I can use a function, else if logic, but want to know your opinion about which design pattern or implementation is better for this kind of casuistry:

```
item.status == 'upcoming' ? 
     'label-upcoming' : 
        ( item.type == 'ticket_required' && 
            item.status == 'available' && 
              item.hasTicket == true ? 
                 'label-ticket' : '')
```

I don´t want a solution, just learn some technics. Thanks in advance

Comment: `function getLabel(item) { if .. else if .. else }` seems the most reasonable and readable.

Comment: Another solution may be for an `item` to return it's own label - ie put @deceze's `getLabel` function on the `item` itself.  You'll get as many different answers as people you ask...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you incorporate multiple conditions for `item.status` here, an object literal that is immediately looked up might be handy:

```
({
  'upcoming': 'label-upcoming',
  'available': item.type == 'ticket_required' && item.hasTicket && 'label-ticket'
}[item.status] || '')
```

(though in this case it's quite ugly as you have a complex expression inside the object, which also has to be evaluated every time even if the key is not picked, and the defaulting from there to `''` is hard to understand). Nonetheless it's a pattern you should know :-) To make it more performant, put the object literal in a static place to avoid creating new objects. If you need it more flexible, put in functions instead of keys:

```
// Using ES6 syntax for conciseness, works with ES5 function expression just as well
const lookup = {
  'upcoming': (_) => 'label-upcoming',
  'available': (item) => item.type == 'ticket_required' && item.hasTicket ? 'label-ticket' : ''
};

… (lookup[item.status] || (_)=>'')(item) …
```

And of course, you can always use an IIFE:

```
… (function() {
    switch(item.status) {
        case 'upcoming':  return 'label-upcoming';
        case 'available': if (item.type == 'ticket_required' && item.hasTicket)
                              return 'label-ticket';
        default: return '';
    }
}()) …
```

Comment: oh nice, that approach is new to me

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I was thinking some kind of approach and was wayting some answer like that.

Answer (score 1):

That's compact but hard to read, I would prefer "`if-else`" for maintainability.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I´m thinking about emulate a Java/C# Enum, and put it inside an if-else and set the Enum. e.g. if (...) type.SOLD else type.UNSOLD, etc

Comment: @Termosfera Or you could [write a Factory Factory Factory](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?joel.3.219431.12&)... There are many ways to skin this cat, and it's unproductive to speculatively discuss about it.

Comment: Thanks @deceze just want to hear some opinions, but you are right.