# ESLint issue with refactoring conditional nested if/else statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ecmascript-6

I wrote a fairly simple function to figure out which hole a golfer has completed playing.  I'm trying to do it the "pretty" ES6 functional way.

In version 1 I have some old-fashioned JS.
Version 2 I think it the most readable and elegant, but ESLint did not like the nested ternary operators.
Version 3 made ESLint happy, but I think it's actually harder to follow and required more functions.

Is there a better, cleaner way to do this following the latest design patters and modern syntax?

Here is a JS Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/pixelwiz/h3r4nv54/2/

```
const startedPlayingRound = holesPlayed => holesPlayed > 0;

const finishedPlayingRound = holesPlayed => holesPlayed === 18;

const playingFromFirstTee = (startHole, holesPlayed) => (
  startHole === 1 && holesPlayed >= 1 && holesPlayed < 18
);

const wrapAroundLogic = (startHole, holesPlayed) => (
  playingFromFirstTee(startHole, holesPlayed) ? holesPlayed :
    ((startHole + holesPlayed) - 1) % 18
);

const finishedOrNotYetStarted = holesPlayed => (
  finishedPlayingRound(holesPlayed) ? 'F' : ''
);

const getThruV1 = (startHole, holesPlayed) => {
  let thru = '';
  if (startedPlayingRound(holesPlayed)) {
    if (finishedPlayingRound(holesPlayed)) {
      thru = 'F';
    } else if (startHole === 1 && holesPlayed >= 1 && holesPlayed < 18) {
      thru = holesPlayed;
    } else {
      thru = ((startHole + holesPlayed) - 1) % 18;
    }
  }
  return thru.toString();
};

const getThruV2 = (startHole, holesPlayed) =>
  !startedPlayingRound(holesPlayed) ? '' :
  finishedPlayingRound(holesPlayed) ? 'F' :
  wrapAroundLogic(startHole, holesPlayed).toString();

const getThruV3 = (startHole, holesPlayed) => (
  finishedPlayingRound(holesPlayed) || !startedPlayingRound(holesPlayed) ?
    finishedOrNotYetStarted(holesPlayed) :
    wrapAroundLogic(startHole, holesPlayed).toString()
);

  $('#v1').html('V1 Result: ' + getThruV1(10, 12));
  $('#v2').html('V2 Result: ' + getThruV1(10, 12));
  $('#v3').html('V3 Result: ' + getThruV1(10, 12));
```

Comment: Just configure eslint so that it uses *your* views on readability and elegance?

Comment: "ESLint did not like the nested ternary operators" - like pretty much everyone else.

Comment: Using `wrapAroundLogic` will call `playingFromFirstTee` twice in your V2. Other than that, it indeed looks like the best choice.