# Ternary expression with multiple conditions

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I am trying to write multiple conditions with ternary expressions in JXS.

But not sure if it's correct.

```
const applyNowUrl = isSmallerThan.medium ? applyNowMobileURL : isEqualOrLargerThan ? applyNowDesktopURL : applyNowTabletURL
```

The "applyNowUrl" const should have 3 different URLs based on screen size.

Comment: Why aren't you sure?

Comment: Because getting this error "do not nest ternary expressions"

Comment: That's a linting "error", not a coding error. You're getting that linting error because nesting ternaries makes code much harder to reason about, compared to things like a function call with `if`s or a `switch`.

Comment: Nested ternary expressions can be difficult to read so I suggest using `if .. else if .. else `. If you really insist on using a ternary expression, I suggest at least using parenthesis `var x = conditiona ? a : (conditionb ? b : c)` to be sure about precedence and make it a bit mor readable. Especially if the conditions are not simple bools.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternative to nested ternary operator in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32289340/alternative-to-nested-ternary-operator-in-js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is correct to have multiple ternary conditions although it makes it difficult to read.

For the sake of clearness, sometimes it's better to create an external function for this:

```
const applyNowUrl = myFucntion(isSmallerThan, isEqualOrLargerThan);

const myFunction = (isSmallerThan, isEqualOrLargerThan) => {
  if (isSmallerThan.medium) return applyNowMobileURL;
  if (isEqualOrLargerThan) return applyNowDesktopURL;
  return applyNowTabletURL;
}
```

Comment: IIFE's are also great for this.

Comment: @Berouminum How so? I.e., what would make an IIFE better, or more readable, than a simple `if`, or a regular function if it's used in multiple places? To me an IIFE makes zero sense here.

Comment: @DaveNewton If you need this in multiple places then an IIFE is obviously useless. However there is no need to declare a named function as he did above if you call it immediately and only once anyway.

Comment: @Berouminum Sure. Given a single use, then, I'm asking why an IIFE over an `if` or a function. There are definitely reasons to break it out into a function, though, like easier testing and extensibility, and easier IoC.

Comment: Let me try this Jose.

Comment: @DaveNewton Using an IIFE has the advantage of being able to use const, which is always great for readability.
I personally find something like this:
`const applyNowUrl = (() => {
 if(isSmallerThan.medium) {
  return applyNowMobileURL;
 }
 if(isEqualOrLargerThan) {
  return applyNowDesktopURL;
 }
 return applyNowTabletURL;
})();`
Easier to read than having some sort of chained if condition.
'_like easier testing_':
This might be true in some cases, but I personally don't think there is much testing to do when it comes to simple if checking.

Comment: Seems Jose’s answer is better way to achieve this. Thanks Joes.

Answer (score 0):

You can have it like this:

```
const applyNowUrl =
    isSmallerThan.medium ? applyNowMobileURL
    : isEqualOrLargerThan ? applyNowDesktopURL
    : applyNowTabletURL
```

You can also use if else recursively